# specific the task_struct in the linux 2.6.30.5

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

in the version 2.6.15,i got that i can rewrite the task_struct in the file (include/linux/sched.h)，like:

```
struct task_struct {  
    unsigned did_exec:1;  
    pid_t pid;  
    pid_t tgid;  
    ...
    char hide;
}
```

but unfortunately,when i come to the version 2.6.30.5,i look through the same file,i just find out a delcration of the task_struct,like:

```
struct task_struct;
```

And i have no idea,which file i should refer to,in purpose of sepcific my own task_struct?

Someone can help me?thx

Answer (score 2):

`struct task_struct` is still defined in [sched.h](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.30.5/include/linux/sched.h#L1117), you just have to keep reading the file.